# I'm trying to design a solution for a day/night color scheme and got stuck

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm working on an app that has a "day" and "night" color palette that can change automatically. We're using Xamarin Forms and, for historical reasons, we're not using XAML but I speak XAML so I'm going to use it in this post.

I've approached it by creating a base type with a property for relevant colors like "dark text" or "header background", then implementing that type for both schemes. Then, I made a type that references one of those and raises a PropertyChanged even if it changes. So a day->night transition involves setting the property, then anything in the UI bound to a path like "ColorScheme.DarkText" changes. Nice.

Now I've got a ViewModel that wants to have different colors for some items in a list. I want those colors backed by this day/night change system, but I might have designed myself into a corner. I'll show you what I did and how I want to redesign, but I'm curious if there's a clever way to go about it without causing other problems.

Here's a VM for an item I'm binding to, let's all assume there's nothing unexpected in ViewModelBase:

```
public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase {

    public string IconColorName { get...; set...; }
    public string IconText { get...; set...; }

}
```

That ViewModel's contained in another boring ViewModel that makes up the rest of the page:

```
public class PageViewModel : ViewModelBase {

    public ObservableColorScheme ColorScheme { get...; set...; }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get...; set...; }

}
```

OK, so what I'm going for is I'd like XAML for my item's template to look something like:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.Children>
        <Label TextColor={Binding IconColor, Converter={StaticResource StringToColorConverter} />
        ...
    </StackLayout.Children>
</StackLayout>
```

Right. OK. So now here's the problem. I can imagine building that `IValueConverter` and setting it up so it has the same concept of the right color scheme, then using the string value here to get the appropriate property. But I have a problem: there can only be one source for a binding, right? I need the color to change if EITHER the `ColorScheme` or `IconColorName` changes. My hunch is WPF could do that, but Xamarin can't?

The most obvious solution I've thought of is some kind of extra ViewModel, in XAML-unfriendly format for brevity:

```
public class ColorViewModel : ViewModelBase {

    public Color Color { get...; set...; }

    public ColorViewModel(string colorName, ObservableColorScheme colorScheme) {
        colorScheme.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => {
            if (e.PropertyName == colorName) {
                Color = colorScheme.Get(colorName);
            }
        }

        Color = colorScheme.Get(colorName);
    }

}
```

I do NOT like this. These items are created and destroyed a lot, so that means that event handler needs to be unsubscribed. I don't want to have to think about that, and I can assume a maintenance programmer will forget. I've thought about retooling it to use a WeakReference for the event subscription but... that's getting really icky.

So I'm not really sure how to proceed, short of making the Page here detect color scheme changes and manually update its child views. That feels icky too. I've been thinking about it for a couple of days and nothing nice is presenting itself.

I'm open to "you're doing this terribly wrong, and there's some feature that would make this dramatically easier for you". I'm suspicious that feature is Styles, which I'm not using because 1) the aforementioned lack of using XAML and 2) our project is older than Style support in Xamarin Forms. Feel free to tell me to throw this design away, but please don't do so without showing me a quick example of the better way!

Comment: why not have ColorScheme or IconColorName each raise TWO PropertyChanged events?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know xamarin nor C#, so maybe I’ll use the wrong terms, but this is how I would approach this problem:
I assume you have some kind of ViewModel hierarchy and you know the root of this hierarchy. 
I would create a ColorScheme class with a static getter of the current color scheme and getters for each color. So you can create a subclass for day and night scheme. Also a void ApplyTo(ViewModelBase). I would create an ViewModelBase interface which has an void UpdateColorScheme() and List Items().

Ok, now, each ViewModel can use the UpdateColorScheme method to setup the view will be created. 
Probably there is some kind of event to change the color scheme. This could be a button or a clock based trigger. This event sets the correct ColorScheme and simply calls ColorScheme.CurrentScheme().ApplyTo(rootViewModel). The ApplyTo method walks down the ViewModel hierarchy and calls UpdateColorScheme() for each ViewModel.

This isn’t very fancy but your don’t have to create dozens of objects for something which will change rarely (only twice a day). You only have one instance of ColorScheme and be instance for each Color and a separate method for color settings. But you don’t have to create and register events listeners all the time. The base class will enforce the maintenance programmer to use this concept so he can not forget to setup a event listener and you use the same code for setting up and updating the view.

And a little side note: opinion based questions are not allowed on Stack Overflow. There is a Core Review Page of StackOverflow, I think this question belongs there.

Comment: The main problem with a static getter is static things, as far as I know, don't play well with data binding in Xamarin. (WPF supported it but I can't find a clear way to do it in Xamarin.)

There are some bits of our code that handle it much in the way you describe, but it's because they were written when we didn't even try to adhere to MVVM so I'm trying to retrofit a good design in.

This comment field is nowhere near large enough to discuss how having views/viewmodels communicate in a circular fashion is sort of counter to MVVM, but what you describe *is* a solution.